# Load all model items in the constructor of a Controller?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

While looking at an example on line, I noticed an interesting way someone was loading their model with their controller.

They were loading the model items through the controllers constructor:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller {

        private List<Items> allItems= new List<Items>();

        public HomeController() {
            LoadItems();
        }

        private void LoadItems() {
           // load all items and cache them
        }
```

This seemed odd to me, as I would load the items I needed in the ActionMethods based upon when I needed them.  So the ListView or the DetailsView or whatever would query the database when needed instead of having "LoadItems" called every time a HomeController method was called.

Just wondering if this is a better way of doing this or just one of many ways to handle MVC.

Comment: Personally, I would not load the models until an action is called that needs the model, not sure why your example is loading them all in the constructor.

Comment: Gotcha.  It made sense to me as I'd have a limited number of "items" at least at launch, but it just seemed like a waste of resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *all* Actions need that list then it is a shorthand. But I suspect this is wasteful.

You are right that it is better to load exactly the needed data in each Action. Even if only one, rarely used Action does not need it.
Personally I think it is clearer too, easier to manage.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that the answer is the one you most often hear in software development:

*It depends.*

Since I have no context as of what exactly this example is loading and what else it consists of, I can't say if this makes sense in this specific instance or not.

But basically I'd agree, in most cases data should be loaded when needed and not all at once at startup. Better apply the YAGNI (You ain't gonna need it) principle whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to do it during the constructor, even if all actions need the models.  The constructor is called even when no action invocation happens.  For example all 404 requests will call the constructor on your default controller.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a very odd way to do it.  I am like you and I like to load the items I need when I need them in specific actions.  Maybe since this was an example lading all items in the constructor was easier.  But I would not write production code that way.